# Why does this code does not help me achieve a blank Tic-tac-toe board?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

here is the codepen, can anyone say why the borders do not display?
I want to achieve this https://codepen.io/javisp91/pen/PmzpLz without the use of class.

I have used nth-of-type and treated the table like a matrix. This code doesn't display borders. What could be overriding?

```
tr td {
    width:100px;
    height: 100px;
}

tr: nth-of-type(1) td: nth-of-type(1) {
    border-right: 5px solid black;
    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}

tr: nth-of-type(1) td: nth-of-type(2) {
    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
    border-right: 5px solid black;
    border-left: 5px solid black;
}

tr: nth-of-type(1) td: nth-of-type(3) {
    border-left: 5px solid black;
    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}

tr: nth-of-type(2) td: nth-of-type(1) {
    border-right: 5px solid black;
    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
    border-top: 5px solid black;
}

tr: nth-of-type(2) td: nth-of-type(2) {
    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
    border-right: 5px solid black;
    border-left: 5px solid black;
    border-top: 5px solid black;
}

tr: nth-of-type(2) td: nth-of-type(3) {
    border-left: 5px solid black;
    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
    border-top: 5px solid black;
}

tr: nth-of-type(3) td: nth-of-type(1) {
    border-right: 5px solid black;
    border-top: 5px solid black;
}

tr: nth-of-type(3) td: nth-of-type(2) {
    border-top: 5px solid black;
    border-right: 5px solid black;
    border-left: 5px solid black;
}

tr: nth-of-type(3) td: nth-of-type(3) {
    border-left: 5px solid black;
    border-top: 5px solid black;
}

body {
    text-align: center;
}

table {
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not defining them correctly. See the following [fork](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XGKqdR) or snippet:

```css
tr td{
 width:100px;
 height: 100px;
}
tr td{
 border-right: 5px solid black;
 border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}
tr td:last-child{
  border-right:0;
}

tr:last-child td{
  border-bottom:0;
}
body{
 text-align: center;
}
table{
 margin: auto;
}
```

```html
 <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td> </td>
   <td> </td>
   <td> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td> </td>
   <td> </td>
   <td> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td> </td>
   <td> </td>
   <td> </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

**Logic:**
Set all `tr td` with right and bottom border except the last one.

```
tr td{
    border-right: 5px solid black;
    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}
tr td:last-child{
  border-right:0;
}

tr:last-child td{
  border-bottom:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

table{
    margin: auto;
  border: solid  // you forget this line in your code put this line to show border. 
}